# How to use apply and lambda functions on set of filtered rows

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply, where-clause

I keeping running into a problem to apply a function to a set of filtered rows of a dataframe in Jupyter notebooks using pandas.

In a nutshell, I have a large dataframe (here I have reduced it) to which I want to add an additional column - R_mf - with values created using filtered rows (eg where depth is greater than 1 but smaller than 3) and apply a function ( Rxo_mf9373 + (T_aq + 6.77) / (df['Temp'] + 6.77)). I have defined the required variables Rxo_mf9373 and T_aq. Can please someone tell me what is wrong with the code?

```
T_aq = 188
Rxo_mf9373 = 0.06
df = pd.DataFrame({'DEPTH':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Temp':[0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]})
df['R_mf'] = df.where((df['DEPTH']>1) & (df['DEPTH'] < 3)).apply(lambda x, T_aq, Rxo_mf9373: Rxo_mf9373 + (T_aq + 6.77) / (x['Temp'] + 6.77), axis = 1)
```

When I run this I get the following:
() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'T_aq' and 'Rxo_mf9373'

Finally, in the presented case above, I wanted to get an output where the dataframe contains an additional column df['R_mf'] and which has only a calculated value from the lambda function in the 2nd row where depth is equal to 2!

Thanks in an advance!

Here is a link to the desired output
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQIdU.png

Answer (score 0):

Davis,
The error "missing 2 required positional arguments" is caused by the fact that the lambda function expects 3 arguments and only receives one. Since those arguments are constants, I suggest you to rewrite your code this way, with single-variable function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DEPTH':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Temp':[0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]})
df['R_mf'] = df.loc[(df['DEPTH']>1) & (df['DEPTH'] < 3), 'Temp'].apply(lambda x: Rxo_mf9373 + (T_aq + 6.77) / x + 6.77)
```

Better yet - get rid of `apply`:

```
df.loc[(df['DEPTH']>1) & (df['DEPTH'] < 3), 'R_mf'] = Rxo_mf9373 + (T_aq + 6.77) / df.loc[(df['DEPTH']>1) & (df['DEPTH'] < 3), 'Temp'] + 6.77)
```